# Unable to send Email to users from my web application using CS50 IDE

Tags: python

I am doing my final project of Harvard CS50 course.
I want to send email to the users in my web application using CS50 IDE with python, flask frame work.
I have tried the following code.

```
    import smtplib, ssl
    port = 465  # For SSL
    smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
    sender_email = "sdrtempsamsung@gmail.com"  # Enter your address
    receiver_email = "sdrtempsamsung@gmail.com"  # Enter receiver address
    password = input("Type your password and press enter: ")
    message = """\
    Subject: Hi there

    This message is sent from Python."""

    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
        server.login(sender_email, password)
        server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

If I run the above code in python independently, it works fine, i.e. The email is sent successfully. But I get the following error when I run it through my web application.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 1031, in __init__
    source_address)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 1037, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 728, in create_connection
    raise err
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
    OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I have reduced the security level of the gmail account being used.

I am very much new with python, flask and C languages.
Any help will be highly appreciated.